# Call action when a specific change is made in edit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created a Crud object to track employee holidays, in my HTTP Post EDIT method I'd like to use an email action (which already works) for when a manager edits a request to change the boolean status from `pending` to `approved`.

Here's what I attempted but my c# is not up to scratch just yet.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "RequestID,EmployeeID,StartDate,FinishDate,HoursTaken,Comments,YearCreated,MonthCreated,DayCreated,YearOfHoliday,Approved,SubmittedBy,ApprovedBy")] HolidayRequestForm holidayRequestForm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (Session["Name"] == null)
        {
            TempData["msg"] = "Your Session Expired - Please Login";
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }

        string name = Session["Name"].ToString();

        var approvedby = db.Employees.Where(s => s.Email.Equals(name)).Select(s => s.Email).FirstOrDefault();
        holidayRequestForm.ApprovedBy = approvedby;

        db.Entry(holidayRequestForm).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        var ApprovedStatus = db.HolidayRequestForms.Select(h => h.Approved) ;

        if ( ApprovedStatus = true){
           SendMailToManager();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.EmployeeID = new SelectList(db.Employees, "EmployeeID", "FullName", holidayRequestForm.EmployeeID);
    return View(holidayRequestForm);
}
```

How do I get it to send the email (call the SendMailToManager() action) when a manager edit the request's status to true?

Comment: `if ( ApprovedStatus = true){` looks _very_ wrong to me.

Comment: Here is the error I'm getting: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<bool?>'`

Comment: @UweKeim Can you explain why? I'm new to c# so I'm making a few mistakes to begin with!

Comment: `=` is an assignment, `==` is a comparison.

Comment: ah okay! that makes a lot of since! thanks unfortunately I got a similar error Error 4 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<bool?>' and 'bool'

Comment: Doesn't seem constructive to me to do try and error via Stack Overflow. If I were you, I would get some decent books/tutorials on C#, Nullables, Entity Framework, and read all of them.

Comment: Okay thanks, appreciate the advice

Comment: @Conor8630 Are you trying to call `SendMailToManager();` if  updated`HolidayRequestForms` has `Approved` true, isn't it?

Comment: Yes!! But I’m having trouble with errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working for anyone who stumbles on this. It was just simply

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "RequestID,EmployeeID,StartDate,FinishDate,HoursTaken,Comments,YearCreated,MonthCreated,DayCreated,YearOfHoliday,Approved,SubmittedBy,ApprovedBy")] HolidayRequestForm holidayRequestForm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            if (Session["Name"] == null)
            {
                TempData["msg"] = "Your Session Expired - Please Login";
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
            }

            string name = Session["Name"].ToString();

            var approvedby = db.Employees.Where(s => s.Email.Equals(name)).Select(s => s.Email).FirstOrDefault();
            holidayRequestForm.ApprovedBy = approvedby;

            db.Entry(holidayRequestForm).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();






            if ( holidayRequestForm.Approved == true){

                SendMailToAreaManager();
                SendMailToManager();
                SendMailToAdmin();

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**variables never to uppercase!**

```
if (ApprovedStatus = true){
     SendMailToManager();
}

TO

if (approvedStatus == true){
     SendMailToManager();
}
```